# Can I run power from inside cabinets to an externally mounted fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, cabinets, conduit

I want to install wall sconce fixtures on the outside of my bathroom cabinets. I have power inside from the wall already. Would it be to code if I cut a hole in the cabinet, mounted a metal box, and ran EMT from the wall to the box? See pictures.

[image: wall sconce fixture]

[image: power inside the wall]

Comment: The main problem with your approach is that it will greatly reduce the usability of the cabinet.

Comment: Yeah, that is a problem. Any ideas of a better way at this point?

Comment: I'd maybe use flat "raceway" rather than EMT.  But that doesn't greatly reduce the size of the boxes.

Comment: And note that the better option might be to put an outlet in the back wall and run a standard rubber power cord from there to the fixture, with no box on the side wall.

Comment: You had me at EMT and metal box. No where on Earth is that *not* ok afaik. It's even in the code that there *be* an outlet just like that in the lower cabinet at the end of a peninsula. The only problem is when the cabinet isn't permanently affixed, and that's one of the only times I get to use BX (in Chicago; EMT-land).

Comment: Can you use a low voltage light instead?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, when doing in-bench or in-cabinet work like that, I am very comfortable with EMT, provided it is anchored properly and not used as a hanger for other things.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can extend the box in the back of the wall with a Raco 665.